# Mailchimp opt-in Laravel 4 tutorial?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, mailchimp, newsletter, mass-emails

Trying to add an opt-in field in the subscription form of my Laravel 4 website which will add the first name, last name and email of the person who subscribes to my Mailchimp mailing list.

Anyone knows a good tutorial for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this by Jeff Mould, its a little bit old.
http://www.jeffmould.com/2013/11/13/how-to-setup-the-mailchimp-api-with-laravel-4/

He uses this package for laravel
https://github.com/hugofirth/laravel-mailchimp